# Chef custom resource property not found

Tags: chef-infra

I have a chef custom resource myresource.rb

```
resource_name :myresource
property :artifact_id, String
property :group_id, String

action :create do
  Chef::Log.info("Package #{artifact_id} Group #{group_id}")
end
```

and i call it from coobook like this.

```
myresource 'myresource' do
  artifact_id "artefict"
  group_id "group"
end
```

but i get following error on that logging:

> NameError: undefined local variable or method `artifact_id'

Any idea what might be wrong? I have also tried:

```
Chef::Log.info("Package #{:artifact_id} Group #{:group_id}")
```

Though this does not throw an error, it outputs:

> Package artifact_id Group group_id

which is not correct.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I solved it. Since Chef version 14, you have to refer to property with resource.property_name, not just property_name. I was a bit confused before, as they were using both types in [Chef Custom Resource Docs](https://docs.chef.io/custom_resources.html), probably they didn't update the entire documentation with the new approach yet.